# jquery: Creating a slide carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create with Jquery simple carousel of images and text. I thought to do this by changing MARGIN - RIGHT each image ,the problem is that when it reaches the end of the UL is empty. How can I create a situation of a loop ? I thought I might do this with "replaceWith" But it's not really going. Thank you.

html:

```
<div class="slider">

  <ul>

    <li class="continer" id="1">

       <div class="text_body">

 <h2> text </h2>
      <p>text</p>

   </div>
    <div class="play"><img src="play.png" alt=""></div>
 <img src="img/01 (8).jpg" alt="">



   </li>


     <li class="continer" id="2">

          <div class="text_body">

         <h2> text </h2>
        <p>text</p>


     </div>
    <div class="play"><img src="play.png" alt=""></div>
   <img src="img/01 (7).jpg" alt="">


       </li>

     <li class="continer" id="3">

    <div class="text_body">
   <h2> text </h2>
    <p>text</p>


   </div>
   <div class="play"><img src="play.png" alt=""></div>
    <img src="img/01 (6).jpg" alt="">

      </li>


      </ul>

        </div>
```

css:

```
   .slider {

        width: 620px;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0px auto;


        }

        ul {

        width: 1882px;
        height: 260px;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin-right: 0px;
        padding-right: 0px;




        }

        li {

        width: 620px;
        height: 260px;
        display: inline-block;





        }

        .text_body {

        float: left;
        width: 180px;
        margin-left: 10px;

        }

        .continer img {

        width: 410px;
        height: 250px;




        }



        .text_body h2 {

            margin-bottom: 5px;



        }

        .play img {

        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        position: fixed;
        margin-top: 183px;
        margin-right: 336px;

        }
```

jquery:

```
        var sliderInt = 1, sliderNext = 2,
        count = $(".continer").size();

        $(function() {


        $(".continer#1").animate({
            marginRight: "-620px",
          }, 1500 );

        startSlider(sliderInt);  function startSlider(sliderNext) {

            count = $(".continer").size();

            console.log(count);


            loop = setInterval(function() {
                $(".continer#" + sliderNext).animate({
            marginRight: "-620px",
          }, 1500 );




                sliderInt = sliderNext;
                sliderNext = sliderInt + 1;

                if (sliderNext > count -1) {


                    $(".continer#" + sliderInt).replaceWith($(".continer#" + sliderNext));






                }





            }, 3000);


        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<h1>Incredibly Basic Slider</h1>
<div id="slider">
  <a href="#" class="control_next">>></a>
  <a href="#" class="control_prev"><</a>
  <ul>
    <li>SLIDE 1</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 2</li>
    <li>SLIDE 3</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 4</li>
  </ul>  
</div>

<div class="slider_option">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
  <label for="checkbox">Autoplay Slider</label>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600);  

html {
  border-top: 5px solid #fff;
  background: #58DDAF;
  color: #2a2a2a;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#slider ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 200px;
  list-style: none;
}

#slider ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
}

a.control_prev, a.control_next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  padding: 4% 3%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #2a2a2a;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a.control_prev:hover, a.control_next:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

a.control_prev {
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
}

a.control_next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
}

.slider_option {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

  $('#checkbox').change(function(){
    setInterval(function () {
        moveRight();
    }, 3000);
  });

    var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
    var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
    var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
    var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

    $('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });

    $('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

    $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

    function moveLeft() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: + slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    function moveRight() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: - slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    $('a.control_prev').click(function () {
        moveLeft();
    });

    $('a.control_next').click(function () {
        moveRight();
    });

});    


Try this codes
```